# Git hook post-receive not running (Ruby script)

Tags: ruby, git

I'm trying to get this script working: https://github.com/zmilojko/git-trello/

In `.git/hooks/post-receive` (with proper values of course):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'git-trello'
GitHook.new(
  :api_key => 'API_KEY',
  :oauth_token => 'OAUTH_TOKEN',
  :board_id => 'TRELLO_BOARD_ID',
  :list_id_in_progress => 'LIST_ID_IN_PROGRESS',
  :list_id_done => 'LIST_ID_IN_DONE',
  :commit_url_prefix => 'https://github.com/zmilojko/git-trello/commits/'
).post_receive
```

File is executable. If I run it in bash (`$ .git/hooks/post-receive`), it seems to work mostly ok (except for the fact it doesn't receive git's input to stdin).

When doing `git push`, the script is not run, and no error whatsoever is thrown. Also, the remote URL is of the form `git@github.com:...`

I'm using `rbenv`, although I don't see how that could be a problem, could it? If it was, at least an error should be shown, like the ruby command wasn't found or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post-receive is a server-side hook. I assume that you are expecting this to run on your local machine, when, from your local machine, you push to GitHub. It doesn't work like that.

Here is a link to all of the server and client side hooks for Git.

http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html#Server-Side-Hooks

Comment: Doh! First time trying to use hooks :)

Comment: Nice to see a question about my code. Just to config what @mbarlocker said, I did make git-trello as a local hook for a local repo. For a GitHub web hook check https://github.com/zanker/github-trello.